# ISV development process

Tags: managed-package, package, isv

What is typical dev process for managed packages. Which orgs it is reasonable to have? I think partner dev orgs for each developer, next - create Partner Dev org(based on EE) for qa where unmanaged packages will be installed initially, uat(Partner Dev org(based on EE)) where demo is shown and BA can make changes. What else should be considered? Maybe it is reasonable to have EE Partner Dev org for uat and its sandboxes for qa. What other environments are nice to have? Which org to choose for packaging org? How orgs organization can be changed when unmanaged package will move to managed?

Answer (score -1):

Determining Your Development Process:

Unmanaged packages are available in: Group, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions
Managed packages are available in: Developer Edition

All packages are unmanaged until you convert them to managed packages. This requires managed packages created in a Developer Edition organization. You may prefer developing managed packages because you can beta test them before a release and offer upgrades for them.

Before creating a package, determine the development process you aim to take so that you can choose the most appropriate type of package for your process:

Developing Unmanaged Packages:

Design your app. See the Force.com Quick Reference for Developing Packages.
Package and upload your app.
Developing Managed Packages

Design your app. See the Force.com Quick Reference for Developing Packages.
Package and upload a beta version of your app.
Gather feedback from your beta testers and make the appropriate fixes to your app.
Package and upload your final version of the app.